# Parallel Gem strange behaviour ruby 2.0.0p0

Tags: ruby, multithreading, concurrency, groovy, parallel-processing

I'm learning a new language, and as I usually learn, programming a simple task, getting anagrams of a word in a dictionary (timed and using threads). Currently while doing the program in Groovy, when I finished it I returned to the program that i made ​​some time ago, to compare the times and memory usage, and it turns out Ruby program ate all resources.

In fact the threads do not start all at the same time but alternate at the beginning and at some time go all in parallel and consume memory.
This fact is different in Groovy, C + +, Python ..

Could you let me know what I'm doing wrong. I can not determine where is the mistake. What could be done to avoid this problem?

PS:  I'm not a english speaker, Sorry if I have misspellings.
PS2: You could try change a keyword to "amor" instead "neuralgica", but with "neuralgica"
occurs the RAM issue.

Running : ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-linux]

Ruby Code:

```
require 'parallel'
require 'time'
require 'benchmark'

class Bot
  def initialize(nombre,diccL,intentos,termine,consola)
    @nombre,@diccL,@intentos,@termine,@consola=nombre,diccL,intentos,termine,consola
  end

  def buscarAlt()
    for intento in @intentos
      for palabra in @diccL
        if palabra[1]==intento
          @consola.synchronize{puts "\n============Anagrama-> " + @nombre+":"+palabra[1]}
          palabra = nil            
        end
        intento = nil
      end
    end
  end
end

class Master  

  def initialize(base)
    #number of bots(CPU cores)
    @K=4
    #Base is the keyword to find the anagrama
    @base=base

    #Loading Dict
    fDicc="alternativo"
    dicc=File.open(fDicc)
    @diccL=Hash.new
    i=0
    dicc.each do |linea|        
      @diccL[i]=linea.to_s.chomp
      i+=1
    end
    dicc.close

    @consola=Mutex.new


    @colaBots=Queue.new

    @permutaciones=@base.split("").permutation.map{|p| p.join("")}

  end

  def iniciar()



    time = Benchmark.realtime do

      inicio=Time.new
      puts "iniciar"

      fin=@K-1
      b=[]
      for i1 in 0..(fin)
        i=i1.to_i;
        b[i]= Bot.new("Bot" + i.to_s,@diccL,@permutaciones[i*(@permutaciones.length/@K)..(i+1)*(@permutaciones.length/@K)],@colaBots,@consola)
      end


      Parallel.map(b) do |bots| 
        bots.buscarAlt()
      end
      @consola.synchronize{puts "termino";fin =Time.new; puts fin.to_i - inicio.to_i }
    end
    puts (time*1000).to_s
  end  
end
```

Groovy Code:

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.gpars', module='gpars', version='1.1.0') 
import static groovyx.gpars.GParsPool.* 
class Consola {
    def synchronized void salida(mensaje) {
        println(mensaje)
    }
    static void main (args){
    }     
}

class Bot {
    def mi_diccionario
    def mi_id 
    def consola
    def palabra
    def permutaciones

    Bot (dict, id, out, word, perm){    
        this.mi_id = id
        this.mi_diccionario = dict
        this.consola = out
        this.palabra = word
        this.permutaciones = perm
    }

    def start() {        
        mi_diccionario.each{d->
            permutaciones.each{p->

                if ( p == d){
                    consola.salida("Anagrama encontrado ->" + d +" por bot:" + mi_id)
                }

            }
        }
    }

}

def benchmark = { closure ->  
    start = System.currentTimeMillis()  
    closure.call()  
    now = System.currentTimeMillis()  
    now - start  
}  


dir = "alternativo"
palabra_original = "neuralgica" //<- is the keyword to find the anagrama
palabras_permutadas = []
c = new Consola()
bots = []
//Number of bots (CPU cores)
nBots = 4

//Loading Dict
fileContents = new File(dir).getText('UTF-8')

palabras = fileContents.tokenize() 

palabra_original.split('')[1..palabra_original.length()].permutations().each {palabra_nueva-> palabras_permutadas.add(palabra_nueva.join())}

def duration = benchmark { 
    nBots.times{    
        bots[it] = new Bot(palabras,it,c,palabra_original,palabras_permutadas[it*(palabras_permutadas.size()/nBots)..((1+it)*(palabras_permutadas.size()/nBots)-1)])    
    }

    withPool {
        bots.eachParallel {        
            it.start()
        }
    }
}
println "execution took ${duration} ms"
```

EDIT: I foud my error, i was using a Hash to save permutations, i changed to String Array, and solve. Ruby was faster than Groovy.

Comment: I realize this isn't the point of the exercise, but you can probably increase performance by building a simple hash where the keys are a sorted array of strings (made by splitting a word) and the values are arrays of words corresponding to that key array. This way each word has only one permutation to calculate - the alphabetical order of the characters - instead of n! permutations.

Comment: I think I understand your idea, and really reduce the number of comparisons because eliminate the words of the dictionary (in this exercise called "Alternativo") that do not start with any of the letters that are not in the search word (in this exercise "amor"). As I get home I will try it with groovy to see that both reduces the time to process. Thanks.